# How to change default folder for video files?

Tags: wordpress

How to change WordPress default upload folder for video files? I want to seperate videos and other medias.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried or researched so far?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great plugin for that,
http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/